# Dialogs tripping up in Vala

Tags: vala

I've been experimenting with Vala programming recently.  I've got pretty extensive experience programming in other languages, but in recent years have stuck mainly with scripting languages like Python, Tcl and Perl.  I was impressed by the clean look of Elementary OS, which is what started me looking into Vala, and I must say that my first impressions are very positive.  However, I have hit a snag with Dialog programming, which I thought more experienced Vala programmers might be able to help with.  In my latest test program I use a Dialog-based routine to obtain a value (getYesNo), and then display a string describing that value to screen using another Dialog-based routine (showDialog).  Both routines work correctly when used independently, but when used together as described the display event is held back until a second call is made to the value-obtaining routine.  This sounds like the sort of situation that a call to "flush_events" would solve in Perl or Tcl.  But how can I deal with it in Vala?  Or is there a way to avoid it happening in the first place?

Code:

```
using Gtk;
using Posix;

public class DialogTestWindow: ApplicationWindow {

    private int RESPONSE;
    private Toolbar tbMain = new Toolbar();
    private ToolButton bAbout = new ToolButton(new Image.from_icon_name
        ("help-about",IconSize.SMALL_TOOLBAR),null);
    private ToolButton bDoIt = new ToolButton(new Image.from_icon_name
        ("media-record",IconSize.SMALL_TOOLBAR),null);
    private ToolButton bQuit = new ToolButton(new Image.from_icon_name
        ("application-exit",IconSize.SMALL_TOOLBAR),null);

    internal DialogTestWindow(DialogTest app) {
        Object(application: app, title: "DialogTest");
        this.window_position = WindowPosition.CENTER;
        this.set_default_size(720,480);
// ---- Set up Toolbar ----------------------------------------------------
        tbMain.get_style_context().add_class(STYLE_CLASS_PRIMARY_TOOLBAR);
        bQuit.is_important = true;
        bQuit.clicked.connect(onQuit);
        tbMain.add(bQuit);
        bAbout.is_important = true;
        bAbout.clicked.connect(onAbout);
        tbMain.add(bAbout);
        bDoIt.is_important = true;
        bDoIt.clicked.connect(onDoIt);
        tbMain.add(bDoIt);
// ---- Pack Toolbar etc into vBox on main window -------------------------
        Box vbMain = new Box(Orientation.VERTICAL,0);
        vbMain.pack_start(tbMain,false,true,0);
        this.add(vbMain);
        this.show_all();
        printf("Started\n");
    }
// ==== getYesNo ==========================================================
    private void getYesNo(string message) {
        Dialog dialog = new Dialog.with_buttons
            ("Get",this,DialogFlags.MODAL,
            Stock.YES,ResponseType.YES,Stock.NO,ResponseType.NO,null);
        var content = dialog.get_content_area();
// warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type
// [enabled by default]
        Label label = new Label(message);
        label.set_line_wrap(true);
        content.add(label);
        dialog.response.connect((id)=>{
            printf("response id=%i\n",id);
            RESPONSE = id;
            dialog.destroy();
        });
        dialog.show_all();
    }
// ==== onAbout ===========================================================
    private void onAbout() {
        Dialog dialog = new Dialog.with_buttons
            ("About",this,DialogFlags.MODAL,
            Stock.OK,ResponseType.OK,null);
        var content = dialog.get_content_area();
// warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type
// [enabled by default]
        Label label = new Label("This program tests pop-up dialogs");
        content.add(label);
        dialog.response.connect(()=>{dialog.destroy();});
        dialog.show_all();
    }
// ==== onDoIt ============================================================
    private void onDoIt() {
        getYesNo("Well?");
        if (RESPONSE==ResponseType.YES) showDialog("YES!");
    }
// ==== onQuit ============================================================
    private void onQuit() {
        printf("Ending\n");
        exit(-1);
    }
// ==== showDialog ========================================================
    private void showDialog(string message) {
        Dialog dialog = new Dialog.with_buttons
            ("Show",this,DialogFlags.MODAL,
            Stock.OK,ResponseType.OK,null);
        var content = dialog.get_content_area();
// warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type
// [enabled by default]
        Label label = new Label(message);
        label.set_line_wrap(true);
        content.add(label);
        dialog.response.connect((id)=>{dialog.destroy();});
        dialog.show_all();
    }

}

public class DialogTest: Gtk.Application {
    internal DialogTest() {
        Object(application_id: "org.test.DialogTest");
    }
    protected override void activate() {
        new DialogTestWindow(this).show();
    }
}

extern void exit(int exit_code);

public int main(string[] args) {
    return new DialogTest().run(args);
}
```

Comment: Could you include some code? Keep in mind that Vala in essence uses GTK+ so you're likely to find the answer in that documentation (dialog, modal dialog, etc).

Comment: Thankyou Simeon (and Happy Christmas!).  I have added the full code at the bottom of the original question.

Answer (score 2):

Use Gtk.Dialog.run, not Gtk.Widget.show_all.  That will block the main loop until the dialog returns a result instead of displaying the two dialogs simultaneously.

Comment: Genius!  Many thanks, nemequ: the dialog test works perfectly now, meaning there is nothing to stop me leaping forward with my application ... (except my slothfulness)